# Cordova app for windows 10 terminated because it took too long to suspend

Tags: angularjs, cordova, uwp

I have an app built using Cordova + AngularJS and I have it working on Android perfectly well but am having some issues with Windows 10.

The app will easily crash when minimizing during a process in the app that takes some time to complete. The only messages I can find about the crash is in the Event Viewer in windows where I receive the following Error:

```
Package xxxxxxxxxxx terminated because it took too long to suspend
```

I have debugged this with Visual Studio 2017 and used the suspend trigger on the tool bar to simulate the same scenario but have not had any additional errors and actually could recreate the same crash.

If anyone has any suggestions on tools to help debug or ideas what the problem could be then please let me know.

Note: I know we need to reduce the time events take to complete in the app. One of the long running things that happens is saving to the device filesystem

Comment: How much codes did you put in `onDeviceReady`? Could you please post your codes?

Comment: The only code ondeviceready is this FastClick.attach($document[0].body); I have made a discovery in the documentation though that says if an app takes longer than 10 seconds to close then windows will automatically kill the app, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-suspend-resume

Comment: Could you please test it on other windows 10 machine, if the problem persists, could you share a demo through online repo?

Comment: Same behavior on windows 10 machine, laptop, tablet ect. Its due to this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-suspend-resume I think we just need to improve the performance of this area of code.